# Raspberry pi webcam server performance issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, webcam, raspbian, motion

I am able to access my raspberry pi webcam server from all the pcs under the same network. But I found lag(>5sec) in the streaming. Is it possible to reduce the lag. any ideas? please share...
Thanks
Regards
Hema Chowdary

Answer (score 0):

Well this depends on what you are using to send and receive the stream but for fun let's say you are using [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), People have reported sub 100 ms over Wifi with the following setup even if I never got it <110ms.

Sender:

```
gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc  device=hw:0  ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=48000, channels=1, endianness=1234, width=16, depth=16, signed=true ! udpsink host=192.168.1.255 port=5000
```

Reciever:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc buffer-size=1 port=5000 ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=48000, channels=1, endianness=1234, width=16, depth=16, signed=true ! alsasink sync=false
```

I did not come up with this configuration for GStreamer but rather SWAP_File did on the official Raspberry Pi forum.

Comment: I am using motion library

Comment: Okay - I have never tried it, could not find much about it either - is there something special about the motion library that you need? Otherwise I would suggest to use a more common streaming library.